# aws-sdk-php deleting object

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, sdk, minio

Am having a very strange problem. Am trying to remove image from the bucket and from DB on my system. Don't know why but it always returns, I tried 10 times and the result is the same.

```
{
    "message": "Image was successfully deleted."
}
```

but the image still exists...
I tried everything why it's doing like that I don't understand
I have permission to delete an image, and my browser does not cache I tried with different browsers and the image still exists...

this is my image delete code

```
    public function deleteImage(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'imageUrl' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 400);
        }

        $validated = $validator->validated();

        $urlPath = parse_url($validated['imageUrl'], PHP_URL_PATH);
        $pathParts = explode('/', $urlPath);


        // images/a6371b07-16d6-455e-9afa-db1e211883e1-heh.jpg ( location / image)
        $imageLocationAndName = implode('/', array_slice($pathParts, -2));

        // bucketName/images/a6371b07-16d6-455e-9afa-db1e211883e1-heh.jpg ( bucket name / location / image)
        $key = ltrim(parse_url($validated['imageUrl'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/');


        // Set up the S3 client
        $s3Client = new S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            ],
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT'),
            'http' => [
                'options' => [
                    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        try {
            // Check if the file exists
            if (!$s3Client->doesObjectExist(env('AWS_BUCKET_NAME'), $imageLocationAndName)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'File not found.',
                ], 404);
            }
            // Delete the S3 object
            $result = $s3Client->deleteObject([
                'Bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET_NAME'),
                'Key' => $key,
            ]);

            // Delete the file from the database
            File::where('url', $validated['imageUrl'])->delete();

            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Image was successfully deleted.',
            ], 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Failed to delete the image.',
            ], 500);
        }
    }
```

Can please someone help me with this problem?

Comment: May be the file has been corrupted?